# How to listen to cocos2d-x mouse & keyboard events?

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, mouse, cocos2d-x

I'm running the proj.mac version of their sample (that comes with the cocos2d-x files).

I saw that the Mac version has EAGLView.mm which has:

```
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
  DISPATCH_EVENT(theEvent, _cmd);
}
```

I made sure to enable the mouse moved events in the AppController.mm:

```
[window setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
```

I can see that it's going there, but what I'm trying to find out is how to make my custom **CCLayer** "register/listen" to the mouse and keyboard events.

The cocos2d-x forums mentioned that they have a **KeyboardTest** in their **TestCase** folder, but I was only able to find a **KeypadTest** which doesn't do much. Also some examples mentioned **CCKeyboardDispatcher**, which is nowhere to be found.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think they may be talking about this patch: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/1849/commits

It's not yet in the mainline. If you do apply it directly you'll hit a few patch rejections and you'll need to manually add the new CCKeyboard* files to your XCode project (Build Phases).

I just pushed up the changes I made to get it to compile (and get KeyboardTest to run in the samples dir):

https://github.com/therealdpk/cocos2d-x/

however, most of the work was not authored by me. I don't know if I'll be able to keep this maintained, either, so use it as a starting point at best.